# Multiple frames of the same type Windows 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have an application for Windows 8 with a page (Frame) for displaying a list of items and a page for downloading & displaying the items details. I am also using MVVM Light for sending notifications.

Application use goes something like this:

1. Open Main Page
2. Navigate to List Page

   ```
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage));
   ```
3. Choose Item

   ```
   //Complete logic
   Frame.GoBack();
   ```
4. Back on Main Page, I start downloading the file in the view model, I send **ONE** NotificationMessage saying BeginDownloadFile and after it is downloaded **ONE** NotificationMessage saying EndDownloadFile.

The first time I do steps 2,3, & 4 my NotificationReceived method is hit once, the second twice and so forth.

```
private async void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
{
    if (msg.Notification == Notifications.BeginDownloadFile)
    {
       FileDownloadPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    else if (msg.Notification == Notifications.EndDownloadFile)
    {
       FileDownloadPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Additional information: I only have one FileDownloadPopup, yet each time, an additional popup is shown each time the NotificationMessageReceived method is called.

My only conclusion is that between navigating forwards and backwards in my app, there are multiple MainPages being created and never closed. This results in many NotificationsMessageReceived methods just waiting for a notification to come their way so they can show their popup.

I have two questions:
1. Does this sound like normal behaviour for a Windows 8 app?
2. How can I close all instances of the MainPage or return to the previous instance without creating a new instance?

**Please let me know if I have missed something important out before marking my question down.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds normal to me. The default navigation behaviour in Windows 8 is to create a new page instance each time you navigate to a new page, regardless of whether this is forward or back navigation.

Try setting the `NavigatinCacheMode` on `MainPage` to `Required`. See the [MSDN documentation for details of how page caching works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I better understand how navigation works after reading the documentation. I was working on the assumption that the pages worked the same way as in WPF. I now need to decide whether to change my logic to work for a new page or cached page each time.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are registering eventhandlers in the page and then not removing them.  Each time you navigate to the page again the handler is being added again in addition to the one you previously added.  Try to add your event handler in OnNavigatedTo, and make sure you unregister it in OnNavigatedFrom.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyEvent.OnDownloadRequest += MyLocalDOwnloadHandler;  // add the handler
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyEvent.OnDownloadRequest -= MyLocalDOwnloadHandler;  // remove the handler
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right, I am registering my event and a solution could be to unregister it as I navigate away from the page. Based on what I have just learned about navigation and pages from ColineE's answer, I need to decide whether to change my logic for a cached page or new page.